# Windows 10 icons display error

Tags: windows-10, icons

I'm running Windows 10 version 1607 (OS Build 14393.693)

Recently after restarting my computer, all icons have either gone missing or not getting displayed properly. Have a look at the following screenshots:

[image: Desktop]

[image: This PC]

I have tried rebuilding the `Icon cache`. I have also started the PC in `safe mode` and rebuild icon cache. But it's all same for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Based on the answer on the linked duplicate: Try a different user, if it works for them, then your user profile is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and looking around, I found out this was caused by corrupted user profile.

Since I was already running the latest build, I had to reset my PC and everything is normal again.